# Mypy - Incompatible types in assignment when assigning different values in alternative branches

Tags: python, mypy

I am wondering why I am getting `Incompatible types in assignment` here?

```py
from typing import cast

import pyvisa
from pyvisa.constants import InterfaceType
from pyvisa.resources import GPIBInstrument, TCPIPInstrument


class Instrument:
    resource_manager = pyvisa.ResourceManager()

    def __init__(self, resource: str):
        self.resource = self.resource_manager.open_resource(resource_name=resource)
        if self.resource.interface_type == InterfaceType.tcpip:
            self.instance: TCPIPInstrument = cast(TCPIPInstrument, resource)
        elif self.resource.interface_type == InterfaceType.gpib:
            self.instance: GPIBInstrument = cast(GPIBInstrument, resource)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Unsupported resource interface type: {self.resource.interface_type}")
```

Gives `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "GPIBInstrument", variable has type "TCPIPInstrument")`

`self.instance` gets correctly the type `instance: TCPIPInstrument | GPIBInstrument` in vscode.

I am using python 3.11.3 and mypy 1.2.0.

[Link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=449310f8b2105a531e2a64157107f02d) to a gist with the same issue, but with slightly different code since I could not get pyvisa to install in the playground.

Found some issues in the code from the comments, here is the more correct code, but still with the same issue.

```py
from typing import cast

import pyvisa
from pyvisa.constants import InterfaceType
from pyvisa.resources import GPIBInstrument, TCPIPInstrument


class Instrument:
    resource_manager = pyvisa.ResourceManager()

    def __init__(self, resource_name: str):
        self.resource = self.resource_manager.open_resource(resource_name=resource_name)
        if self.resource.interface_type == InterfaceType.tcpip:
            self.instance = cast(TCPIPInstrument, self.resource)
        elif self.resource.interface_type == InterfaceType.gpib:
            self.instance = cast(GPIBInstrument, self.resource)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Unsupported resource interface type: {self.resource.interface_type}")
```

Comment: It is in line the `self.instance = cast(GPIBInstrument, resource)`

Comment: because you already did: `self.instance: TCPIPInstrument`

Comment: also, the `cast` is very strange, why is the argumented annotated by `resource: str`

Comment: Same error I remove the `: TCPIPInstrument`

Comment: because it still infers it from `cast(TCPIPInstrument, resource)`

Comment: Miss by me, I will edit question with updated code. I still get the same error however.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I understand that it infers it, but I want `self.instance` to have the type `TCPIPInstrument | GPIBInstrument`, not the first one I cast. Is that possible?

Comment: just annotate it at the top, right before the `if` statement: `self.instance: TCPIPInstrument | GPIBInstrument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.instance` can only have one type, which is bound when it's first declared; mypy won't widen a variable's type when you assign a new value to it (indeed, part of the point of declaring a type is to keep you from accidentally mixing types for a single variable in different logic branches).  It sounds like the VSCode plugin's typechecker does something different and it automatically infers the type as a union; it'd presumably do the same thing if you did something like:

```
foo = "123"  # type is str
foo = 123    # type is now str|int I guess?
```

For mypy's purposes, if you want the variable's type to be a union, you need to specify that explicitly when it's first declared:

```
        if self.resource.interface_type == InterfaceType.tcpip:
            self.instance: GPIBInstrument | TCPIPInstrument = cast(TCPIPInstrument, resource)
        elif self.resource.interface_type == InterfaceType.gpib:
            self.instance = cast(GPIBInstrument, resource)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Unsupported resource interface type: {self.resource.interface_type}")
```

Since the variable will be bound to the same union type regardless of which of the two actual types it has at runtime, you can remove some code duplication by just doing a single `cast` to that type:

```
if self.resource.interface_type in (InterfaceType.tcpip, InterfaceType.gpib):
    self.instance = cast(GPIBInstrument | TCPIPInstrument, self.resource)
else:
    raise TypeError(f"Unsupported resource interface type: {self.resource.interface_type}")
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem. I tried adding `GPIBInstrument | TCPIPInstrumen` to both assignments, and that did not work. However just adding it to the first assignment as you showed works. :)

Comment: Updated answer with a suggestion on a simpler way to write this code (instead of doing two `casts` to two different types and one explicit union type declaration that encompasses both, you can just do a single `cast` to the desired union type, which gives `self.instance` the correct type through inference).

Answer (score 1):

Mypy infers the type of a variable from the first assignment it sees (which coincides with the annotation here).

If you assign a value with an unrelated type in another statement, it's a type error.

It looks as if the two types are not entirely unrelated. You can teach Mypy this by declaring the type of the variable before the first assignment,  either as a union of the two types or as a common supertype.